# Is array item order is preserved in a MongoDB document?

Tags: mongodb

**Context**

- I have an object which somewhere in the hierarchy contains an array or a list (either C# or Python client)  .
- I persist this  object to a MongoDB collection.
- I query back this document from the MongoDB server (either C# or Python client) and have back my object

**Question**

Is array or list item order is preserved? I mean what was the value originally at index 0 will be also the value or index 0, etc?

**PS**

As I see it depends on three factors... let me correct if I am wrong

- The particular client library what I used when persisted the data
- The server specification
- The particular client library what I used when I retrieved the data.

So all the three must conform to preserving array item order to successfully preserve...
Is there anywhere it is specified?

Comment: It would be strange if it _wasn't_ preserved.

Comment: One of the key feature of arrays is the order of the items (as oppose to sets for example). mongodb is no different, and as long as you will not use set operators specifically (such as `$setIntersection` for example), the order of items will be preserved

Comment: @AKX Agree, however we've seen strange things... The key is, is there it specified somewhere? (similar to json serialize/deserialize, which specifies that the order of an array is **significant**). S

Comment: BSON Arrays are detailed in [Specification Version 1.1](https://bsonspec.org/spec.html).  TLDR; _"The document for an array is a normal BSON document with integer values for the keys, starting with 0 and continuing sequentially. For example, the array ['red', 'blue'] would be encoded as the document {'0': 'red', '1': 'blue'}. The keys must be in ascending numerical order."_

Comment: "_Agree, however we've seen strange things_" - perhaps you should describe those conditions (eg the symptoms of the underlying problem/strangeness) to get better feedback? Right now it feels like we're talking in generalities at a high level rather than dealing with your specific configuration/environment/issue